# when should the "SQL" tag be used?

Tags: discussion, faq, tagging

It looks like the SQL tag is used incorrectly for some questions.

Should it only be used when the question is really about SQL? Or is it OK to ask it for a question like: 
[How to determine if an Index is required or necessary](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56/how-to-determine-if-an-index-is-required-or-necessary)
[How do you test for race conditions in a database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148/how-do-you-test-race-conditions-in-a-database)

It seems like non-DBA types might put SQL on anything they ask because that is kind of how they think of DB questions compared to the rest of their world.

Should "SQL" only be used as a tag if the question is actually a SQL question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the [tag:sql] tag is in the process of being burninated as explained in [Let's burninate the SQL tag!](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3038/15356) and [Please help us delete the SQL tag!](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3094/15356).

Comment: In fact, it has been [burninated already](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3104).

Answer (score 7):

"Should "SQL" only be used as a tag if the question is actually a SQL question?"

### Yes

SQL tag could be misused a lot. Is should be used just when the question has a direct relation with SQL.

Answer (score 4):

I think we better avoid a sql tag and use more specific tags.

> What is actually a SQL question ?

Would all users use this in a consistent way?

Let's try to keep our tags informative.

Comment: But what will someone who has a sql question use for the tag then? For instance what would have been used for http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83/order-by-using-custom-priorities-for-text-columns

Comment: Hhm. Perhaps 'SELECT' or just 'ORDER BY'.

Comment: SQL used as a tag for SQL questions allows SQL questions to be listed separately, added to a favorite or ignore list, and have a separate FAQ, top users, etc.  These are benefits that are not as simple to attain with more specific tags.  I'm not saying more specific tags should not exist, merely that an SQL tag has merit.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes** because in addition to @[bigown](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/41/bigown)'s answer we do allow databases on here that are **not** SQL such as the NoSQL databases and even MS Access. However it should not be used, and should be retagged if the question doesn't actually have anything to do with some SQL dialect